# Cannot Enable Minify while implementing Huawei Remote Config

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to implement Huawei Remote Config to my application. But whenever I enable minify, I got an error like following. Does anybody have any idea how I can solve this problem?

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOBSp.png)

```
com.huawei.agconnect.exception.AGCServerException:
code: 2 message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ONLY ONE String Field can be annotated as Url      
at c.i.a.f.g.b(Unknown Source:72)            
at c.i.a.f.g.a(Unknown Source:0)
at c.i.a.f.k.a(Unknown Source:2)
at c.i.a.f.d$b.a(Unknown Source:6)         
at c.i.a.f.i$a.a(Unknown Source:14)        
at c.i.a.f.i$a.call(Unknown Source:0)      
at c.i.d.a.j.f$a.run(Unknown Source:4)   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)   
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)            
at com.huawei.agconnect.credential.obs.i$1.onFailure(Unknown Source:115)      
at c.i.d.a.j.c$a.run(Unknown Source:27) at c.i.d.a.h$a.execute(Unknown Source:0)
at c.i.d.a.j.c.onComplete(Unknown Source:19)     at c.i.d.a.j.e.f(Unknown Source:21)          
at c.i.d.a.j.e.a(Unknown Source:19)         
at c.i.d.a.g.a(Unknown Source:2)             
at c.i.d.a.j.f$a.run(Unknown Source:15)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)   
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Comment: Remove applying proguard, does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My proguard-rules.pro was missing following line:

`-keep class com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}`

All my HMS ruels:

```
# HMS Core classes
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keep class com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
-keep class com.hianalytics.android.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.updatesdk.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hms.**{*;}

# HMS Remote Config
-keep class com.huawei.agconnect.remoteconfig.*{*;}
-keepclassmembers class **{
    public <init>(android.content.Context,com.huawei.agconnect.AGConnectInstance);
}
-keepclassmembers class com.huawei.agconnect.remoteconfig.internal.server.**{*;}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not related gargle issue,I hope you missed configuration flow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about minify but it might not be supported. The [Codelab](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#7) also suggests to turn it off. I hope it is not too necessary for your project but if I understood you correctly with it being turned off, everything compiles without any issues, right?

Answer (score 0):

I use these rules:

```
-keep class com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
-dontwarn com.huawei.agconnect.**
-keepattributes SourceFile, Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses, LineNumberTable
-ignorewarnings 
-keepattributes *Annotation* 
-keepattributes Exceptions 
-keepattributes InnerClasses 
-keepattributes Signature  
-keep class com.huawei.hianalytics.**{*;} 
-keep class com.huawei.updatesdk.**{*;} 
-keep class com.huawei.hms.**{*;} 
-keep interface com.huawei.hms.analytics.type.HAEventType{*;}
-keep interface com.huawei.hms.analytics.type.HAParamType{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalyticsInstance{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalytics{*;}
```

(Referenced a combination of [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-getting-started-0000001055756858#section1448912915419) and [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-apm-android-getstarted-0000001052887262))

Are you also sure you are using Huawei Remote Configuration correctly?

You need this in your root build.gradle:

```
buildscript { 
  repositories { 
    ...
    maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'} 
  } 
}
 
buildscript { 
  dependencies { 
    ...
    classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.2.300'
  } 
}
```

Then these dep's in your app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.300'
  implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-remoteconfig:1.5.2.300'
  implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.0.0.300'
```

Then instantiate and pull the config:
(If you don't pullguard might strip them as unused)

```
private lateinit var config: AGConnectConfig
private lateinit var analytics: HiAnalyticsInstance
 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    config = AGConnectConfig.getInstance()
    analytics = HiAnalytics.getInstance(this)
    config.fetch(0) // a value of 0 here is for DEBUGGING ONLY, delete for prod (giving a 12 hour refresh period)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        config.apply(it)
        Log.d(TAG, "Applied")
        updateUIBasedOnRemoteConfig()
    }
```

Reference: https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/remote-configuration-using-appgallery-connect/